# Changing array of numbers into array of objects jq

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq

I'm totally brand new to JSON and jq so this might seem like a simple question.
I'd like to change an array of numbers into an array of objects with a key for each value (number).

Let's say I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
"foo": [1519739200, 1519739600, 1519740000]
}
```

Then my desired output would be:

```
{
"foo": [
    {
       "id": 1519739200
    },
    {
       "id": 1519739600
    },
    {
       "id": 1519740000
    },
  ]
}
```

So far everything I've seen was connected with adding new keys with values to existing object or merging two arrays into few objects. I know that I can add more keys into already existing object but how can I add keys to an array? I assume I have to change array elements into objects first but how do I do it?
Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

https://jqplay.org/s/xF9DyVbhXD

```
{ foo : [ { id : .foo[] } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about it.

First you want to create a new object for each item in foo:

```
$ jq -c '{ id: .foo[] }'
{"id":1519739200}
{"id":1519739600}
{"id":1519740000}
```

You can then rebuild the "shape" you had - first with `[ ... ]`

```
$ jq -c '[ { id: .foo[] } ]' 
[{"id":1519739200},{"id":1519739600},{"id":1519740000}]
```

Then the `{ foo: }`

```
$ jq -c '{ foo: [ { id: .foo[] } ] }' 
{"foo":[{"id":1519739200},{"id":1519739600},{"id":1519740000}]}
```

Another option is to use `|=` to modify/update `.foo` directly.

```
$ jq -c '.foo |= [{id: .[]}]' 
{"foo":[{"id":1519739200},{"id":1519739600},{"id":1519740000}]}
```